# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error using v-dialog component twice on the same view with Vue Observable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

When I open and close the v-dialog I get:

```
VDialog.ts:238 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts:238)
    at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts:238)
    ...
```

My view includes the same component twice as you can see below. Each uses a different slot. If I include the component once I do not get this error.

How to replicate the error:
1. Open the dialog
2. click `close` on on the dialog card
3. re-open the dialog
4. Click `close` again
5. The error appears

**Main.vue**

```
<CreateProjectDialog>
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
        <v-btn v-on="slotProps.dialog.on" color="primary" class="white--text">
            Project <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>    
    </template>
</CreateProjectDialog>

<CreateProjectDialog>
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
        <v-btn
            v-on="slotProps.dialog.on"
            class="ma-5 mr-md-12"
            fixed
            x-large
            fab
            bottom
            right
            color="primary"
        >
            <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>  
    </template>
</CreateProjectDialog>
```

**CreateProjectDialog** component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="600px">

            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <slot v-bind:dialog="{ on }"></slot>     
            </template>

            <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
                <v-card>

                    <v-card-title class="justify-center">
                    </v-card-title>

                    <v-card-text>
                    </v-card-text>

                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1 white--text" @click="submitProject" :disabled="!valid">Create</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>

                </v-card>
            </v-form>

        </v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>
```

I use this computed property to calculate the dialog value through an observer in store.js

**createProjectDialog** component

```
    computed: {
        dialog: {
            get () {
                return getters.projectDialog();
            },
            set (val) {
                mutations.toggleProjectDialog(val);
            }
        }
    },
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const state = Vue.observable({
    projectDialog: false
});

export const getters = {
    projectDialog () {
        return state.projectDialog;
    }
};

export const mutations = {
    toggleProjectDialog (val) {
        state.projectDialog = val;
    }
};
```

If I remove the computed property `dialog` entirely, and instead return a normal data property it works.

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            dialog: false
        }
    }
}
```

I want to understand why this happens exactly and how I can make it work with the observer.

Is there a better way of handling this instead of using slots?

Comment: Some things that may or may not be related:  1) You shouldn't call a mutation directly; only through an action.  But if you do, call it with `commit`, not `mutations`.  2) In `dialog`'s `getter`, the Vuex getter is being called like a function which isn't right here.  It should be `return getters.projectDialog;` (no invocation at the end).  The error indicates an infinite loop, which makes me thing that `dialog's` setter triggers its getter endlessly, but I didn't see that with some quick testing.

Comment: Did you confuse my code with Vuex? Because I am not using vuex. I am new with observables so I am not sure if point 1 is right or wrong.

Comment: I looked at this article for implementing observables https://austincooper.dev/2019/08/09/vue-observable-state-store/

Comment: Oops, yeah I did